# Differences between 2 styles of default implementations in a trait?

Tags: rust

There are 2 ways to provide methods for a Trait itself, Rustdoc distinguishes them by saying "provided methods" and `impl dyn XXX`. For example:

```rust
trait Trait {
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("Default implementation");
    }
}

impl Trait {
    fn bar(&self) {
        println!("Anonymous implementation?");
    }
}
```

I noticed it when I was reading the documentation of Rust's [`failure`](https://docs.rs/failure/0.1.5/failure/trait.Fail.html) crate.

What are the use cases for them? What are the differences?

Answer (score 11):

The first snippet,

```
trait Trait {
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("Default implementation");
    }
}
```

implements a *provided method* on the trait. This method can be overridden by a trait implementation, but it does not have to be overridden.

The second snippet,

```
impl Trait {
    fn bar(&self) {
        println!("Anonymous implementation?");
    }
}
```

implements an *inherent method* on a *trait object* of type `dyn Trait`. Method implementations for `dyn Trait` can only be called for trait objects, e.g. of type `&dyn Trait`. They can't receive `self` by value, since `dyn Trait` does not have a size known at compile time, and they **can't be called on *concrete types* implementing `Trait`** (including generic types with a `Trait` bound).

The modern notation is to write `impl dyn Trait` instead of `impl Trait`, and in fact this notation was [one of the motivating examples for the introduction of the `dyn` keyword](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2113-dyn-trait-syntax.md#the-current-syntax-is-often-ambiguous-and-confusing) – the old syntax did not provide any clues as to what the semantics are, whereas the new syntax with the `dyn` keyword hints at the fact that this impl is only used together with dynamic dispatch.

A trait object is a *fat pointer* to an object implementing `Trait`, but the concrete type of the object is not necessarily known at compile time. The fat pointer contains a pointer to the object data, as well as a pointer to the virtual method table of the object type. The latter is used to dynamically dispatch to the correct trait implementation at runtime.

It is rather uncommon to use `impl dyn Trait`. Generally it's only useful if you want to make use of some dynamic type information, like downcasting to the actual type. The only traits with inherent methods on trait objects in the standard library are [`Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/any/trait.Any.html) and [`Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/error/trait.Error.html).

Answer (score 3):

In short: one can be overridden, and the other cannot.

When you define a trait, you define items that implementations of the trait may (or have to) override:

```
trait Trait {
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("Default implementation");
    }
}

impl Trait for i64 {
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("i64 implementation: {}", self);
    }
}
```

On the other hand, using `impl Trait`, you define *inherent* methods, which cannot be overridden:

```
impl Trait {
    fn bar(&self) {
        self.foo();
        self.foo()
    }
}

// Try:
impl Trait for i64 {
    fn bar(&self) { ... } // error: bar cannot be overridden.
}
```

As a result, inherent traits methods act as the [Template Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern): they provide a canvas linking together one or multiple overridable method(s).

If you look at the `failure` crate that you linked, the method `Failure::find_root_cause()` states:

> This is equivalent to iterating over `iter_causes()` and taking the last item.

You may consider those inherent methods to be *convenience methods*, methods providing an easy/intuitive interface for common tasks which *can* be accomplished manually... but are conveniently pre-defined.

*Note: any inherent method could be implemented as a free function taking the trait as a first argument; however free functions cannot be called in method position.*

Comment: I don't remember seeing "inherent method" in Rust's documentation, so I assume this is a general term in computer science?

Comment: @seamlik: I don't have much of a CS background, so I have no idea. In Rust, it's often used to differentiate the methods *inherent* to a type (`impl Struct`), which you can access immediately after importing said type, from the methods a type gains from implementing traits, which can only be accessed once the trait was imported.

Comment: I think this answer misses the main difference: `impl Trait` is short for `impl dyn Trait`, and the methods are only available for _trait objects_, e.g. `&dyn Trait`. You can't call them on a concrete type implementing `Trait`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: That's a difference I had completely missed. Interestingly, you cannot even call it on `T: Trait + 'static`. Do you know if this is in any way linked to the [Fragile Base Class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class) issue? In any case, I would encourage you to answer yourself so I can upvote you.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I've added another answer. The reason you can't call it on `T: Trait` is that `T` is still a concrete type, which is monomorphised to the actual type at compile time. I don't think this has anything to do with the fragile base class issue.